# an object is deallocated on iOS5, but not on iOS4. how to trace?

Tags: objective-c, ios, error-handling

I have this method (someone else wrote it!)

```
- (IBAction)showMasterPopover:(id)sender
{
if (_hiddenPopoverController && !(_hiddenPopoverController.popoverVisible)) {

// Inform delegate.
if (_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(splitViewController:popoverController:willPresentViewController:)]) {
[(NSObject <MGSplitViewControllerDelegate> *)_delegate splitViewController:self popoverController:_hiddenPopoverController  willPresentViewController:self.masterViewController];
}

// Show popover.
[_hiddenPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:_barButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

}
else if (_hiddenPopoverController.popoverVisible) 
{
    [_hiddenPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

}

and after a few very reproducible steps

```
[_hiddenPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:_barButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

crashes the app with the following:

```
*** -[ServerFolderController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x85a9080
```

This crashes on iOS5.x, but not on iOS4. Any ideas ?
From the Instruments I gather that there is a Zombie object.

I'm stumped! 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is NORMAL ) to crash in iOS5 and not to crash in iOS4. From my personal expirience Apple changed many internal "things" in iOS5 so my applications may crash in iOS5 when it was stable in iOS4. But!!! In all cases it was my fault and my error with not enough retain or with wrong autorelease. So only you can find "this bug" in you code. I think something wrong with you delegate object.

Comment: I found the release that was causing the crashing. thanks for the tips.